# Extract string before last occurence of a charcacter

Tags: sql, postgresql

My Specs:
Postgres 9.6.6, latest Ubuntu LTS

I need to exctract a part of a tring before the last occurence of a caracter:
exaple with a '.'

```
'ab.cde.fghi' -> 'ab.cde'
```

at moment this is my code:

```
select 
 substr('ab.cde.fghi',1,length('ab.cde.fghi')-strpos(reverse('ab.cde.fghi'),'.'))
```

I 'm looking for a more funcional/elegant way to do that.
Any suggestion is apreciated.

Thanks
Perez.

Comment: Probably most elegant solution is some clever Regex :)

Comment: Sure, Regex is a must for text, but I am looking a solution using database functions

Comment: PostgreSQL supports regex natively: **[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9497f733276bfed6c3fb84ad07ea4fa0)** https://stackoverflow.com/a/52207871/5070879

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use arrays:

```
SELECT c, sub.arr[array_upper(arr, 1)-1]  
FROM tab
,LATERAL (SELECT string_to_array(tab.c, '.'))sub(arr)
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e715d5c8c4d611e1364270a5ef6f84a0)**

And if you don't like `LATERAL` just copy-paste:

```
SELECT c,
  (string_to_array(tab.c, '.'))[array_upper((string_to_array(tab.c, '.')), 1)-1]
FROM tab
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [a regular expression:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

```
select substring('ab.cde.fghi' from '(.*)\.')

 substring 
-----------
 ab.cde
(1 row)
```

Comment: I think this is the most appropriated for a production, thanks. I accept @lukasz-szozda because it use only SLQ language, that is what I am looking for in this question.